# Null Pointer Exception In sqlite Database

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite, android-logcat

I'm coding an android application that allows a user to search in a database and see results from the database based on their search. Currently I am receiving a NullPointerException and I am not really sure how to get around this problem as I have tried many things to make sure the cursor is not empty these lines that are throwing the error have the (*) in front of them..  My code is listed below as well as the logcat. . I am using eclipse sdk 4.2 and am testing this on my Motorola Droid Bionic as well as an Emulator.  I am new to programming in android and everything I've learned has been from a tutorial or other online resources. Any help is greatly appreciated

Main Activity where the Database is Created:

```
  package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity 
{

    EditText dEdit;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";


    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LocalDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Business";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Business (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "business text not null, address text not null, phone text not null,hours text not null,website text not null,type text not null" 
        + ")";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public MainActivity(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private  class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            try{
            mDB=db;
            mDB.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {   
            try{
                mDB=db;
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            mDB.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Business");
            onCreate(mDB);
            }catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public MainActivity open() throws SQLException 
    {
        mDB = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertTitle(String business, String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WEB, hours);
        initialValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_BUSINESS,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_HOURS,
                KEY_WEB,
              KEY_TYPE}, 
                null, 
              null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                mDB.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_BUSINESS, 
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_PHONE,
                        KEY_HOURS,
                        KEY_WEB,
                        KEY_TYPE
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String business, 
    String address, String phone, String hours, String website, String type) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_BUSINESS, business);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_HOURS,hours);
        args.put(KEY_WEB,website);
        args.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        return mDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }



    }

    public Cursor getBusinessInfo(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business  where name like ?", new String[]{"%"+name+"%"}); 
    }

    public Cursor getBusinessType(String type) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mDB.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business  where type like ?", new String[]{"%"+type+"%"}); 
    }
}
```

Where the search is happening in the DB:

```
package com.example.database;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class DBUse extends Activity  {
    EditText dEdit;
    SQLiteDatabase data;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_BUSINESS = "business";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
    public static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
    public static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MainActivity datab = new MainActivity(this);

        Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
        buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);



        Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
        buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);

        dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        datab.open();


        Cursor c = datab.getAllTitles();
        if((c!=null) &&c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{DisplayTitle(c);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }   
        datab.open();
        Cursor b = datab.getAllTitles();

        if ((b!=null) && b.moveToFirst())
            DisplayTitle(b);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





    }



//displays the data

    public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)  {
        Toast.makeText(this,
        "Name: " + c.getString(1)+"\n"+
        "Address:" + c.getString(2)+"\n"+
        "Phone:" + c.getString(3)+"\n"+
        "Hours:" + c.getString(4)+"\n"+
        "Website"+ c.getShort(5)+
        "Type" + c.getShort(6),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    //Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick (View v) {

            Cursor cur = data.getBusinessInfo(dEdit.getText().toString());
            String result="";

            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                    +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";
                      Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            };
            return;
        }

    };      
//Informs the user what is being searched
    private OnClickListener startType=new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick (View v){
            Cursor cur=data.getBusinessType(dEdit.getText().toString());
            String result="";
            int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_BUSINESS);
            int iAddress=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS);
            int iPhone=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
            int iHours=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOURS);
            int iWebsite=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_WEB);
            int iType=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_TYPE);
            Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, "Searching by Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  log.d("result",DBUse.getString(0));
            for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()){
                result=result +cur.getString(iRow) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iName) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iAddress) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iPhone) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iHours) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iWebsite) + " "
                        +cur.getString(iType) + " " + "\n";
                        Toast.makeText(DBUse.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            };
            return;
        };


    };

}
```

Where the Data is coming from:
    package com.example.database;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    public class DBActivity extends Activity {
        //MainActivity eventsData;
        //EditText output;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            MainActivity db= new MainActivity(this);

```
        //output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        //type.setOnClickListener(
        //      new OnClickListener(){
        //          public void onClick(View view){
        //              Log.v("Entry",dEdit.getText().toString());
            //      }
        ///     });


        //try{String destPath="/data/data" +getPackageName()+ "/databases/BloomBusiness";
        //  File f = new File(destPath);
        //  if(!f.exists()){
        //      CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("db"), new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        //  }
        //  
        //  
        //}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}catch(IOException e){
        //  e.printStackTrace();
        //}

        db.open();

        //inserting all data
        long id; 
        id =db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","419 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");


        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","316 W. 6th Street Bloomington, IN", "812-333-5300", "M-Sat:7AM-10PM Sun:9AM-9PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("BloomingFoods","3220 E. 3rd Street Bloomington, IN", "812-336-5300", "M-Sun:8AM-10PM","http://www.bloomingfoods.coop","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Uptown Cafe","102 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-0900", "M-Sat:8AM-9PM Sun:9AM-8PM", "http://www.the-uptown.com/","Cajun-Creole");
        id=db.insertTitle("Crazy Horse","214 W. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-8877", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun:Noon-Midnight", "http://www.crazyhorseindiana.com/","Restaurant & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("FARMbloomington","108 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-0002", "Tue.-Thurs.:8AM-10PM F:8AM-1AM Sat: 10AM-3AM Sun: 10AM-10PM","http://www.farm-bloomington.com","Grocery");
        id=db.insertTitle("Laughing Planet","322 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2233", "M-Sun:11AM-9PM","http://www.facebook.com/laughingplanetbtown","Burritos & Salads");
        id=db.insertTitle("Soma Coffeehouse","322 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-331-2770", "M-Sat:7AM-11PM Sun:8AM-11PM","http://www.iheartsoma.com","Coffee House");
        id=db.insertTitle("Upland Brewing Company","350 W. 11th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2337", "M-Thurs:11AM-Midnight F-Sat:11AM-1AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.uplandbeer.com","Brewery & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("Nick's English Hut","423 E. Kirkwood Bloomington, IN", "812-332-4040", "M-Sat:11AM-2AM Sun: Noon-Midnight","http://www.nicksenglishhut.com","Bar & Restaraunt");
        id=db.insertTitle("The Village Deli","409 E. Kirkwood Ave. Bloomington, IN", "812-336-2303", "M-F:7AM-8PM Sat-Sun 8AM-8PM","http://www.villagedeli.biz","Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner");
        id=db.insertTitle("Rachael's Cafe","300 E. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-330-1882", "M-F:8AM-9PM Sat-Sun 9AM-9PM","http://www.rachaelscafe.com","Coffee House & Live Music");
        id=db.insertTitle("Happy Pig","1604 W. 7th St. Bloomington, IN", "None", "W:Sample Gates Noon-3PM Thurs:Sample Gates Noon-3PM F:Atlas Bar 11:30PM-3:30AM Sat:Courthouse Square 11:30PM-3:30AM","http://www.happypigbloomington.com","BBQ Streetfood");
        id=db.insertTitle("Lennie's Restaurant and Brewpub","1795 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-323-2112", "Sun-Th:11AM-11PM F-Sat 11AM-Midnight","http://www.lenniesgourmetpizza.com","Bar & Restaurant");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1791 E. 10th St. Bloomington, IN", "812-339-7737", "Sun-Tues:11AM-2AM Wed-Thur: 11AM-3AM F-Sat:11AM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","1610 W. 3rd St. Bloomington, IN", "812-332-2522", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
        id=db.insertTitle("Pizza X","877 S. College Mall Rd. Bloomington, IN", "812-355-5000", "Sun-Wed:4PM-Midnight Thur: 4PM-3AM F-Sat:4PM-4AM","http://www.pizzaxbloomington.com","Pizza");
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-28 18:06:32.648: E/Trace(692): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 18:06:33.160: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 2% free 10842K/11011K, paused 44ms, total 46ms
04-28 18:06:33.160: I/dalvikvm-heap(692): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.204MB for 614416-byte allocation
04-28 18:06:33.298: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 88ms+4ms, total 135ms
04-28 18:06:33.368: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
04-28 18:06:33.381: I/dalvikvm-heap(692): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.245MB for 1093136-byte allocation
04-28 18:06:33.498: D/dalvikvm(692): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12508K/12743K, paused 76ms+7ms, total 126ms
04-28 18:06:34.188: D/gralloc_goldfish(692): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-28 18:07:12.528: D/AndroidRuntime(692): Shutting down VM
04-28 18:07:12.528: W/dalvikvm(692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.example.database.DBUse$2.onClick(DBUse.java:123)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 18:07:14.911: I/Process(692): Sending signal. PID: 692 SIG: 9
04-28 18:10:06.128: E/Trace(711): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-28 18:10:07.179: D/dalvikvm(711): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 2% free 10842K/11011K, paused 70ms, total 71ms
04-28 18:10:07.188: I/dalvikvm-heap(711): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.204MB for 614416-byte allocation
04-28 18:10:07.258: D/dalvikvm(711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 28ms+14ms, total 71ms
04-28 18:10:07.318: D/dalvikvm(711): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 11441K/11655K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
04-28 18:10:07.330: I/dalvikvm-heap(711): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.245MB for 1093136-byte allocation
04-28 18:10:07.461: D/dalvikvm(711): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 12508K/12743K, paused 26ms+4ms, total 129ms
04-28 18:10:07.461: D/dalvikvm(711): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
04-28 18:10:08.179: D/gralloc_goldfish(711): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-28 18:10:30.158: D/AndroidRuntime(711): Shutting down VM
04-28 18:10:30.158: W/dalvikvm(711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.example.database.DBUse$1.onClick(DBUse.java:94)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-28 18:10:30.168: E/AndroidRuntime(711):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 18:10:32.229: I/Process(711): Sending signal. PID: 711 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 18:07:12.542: E/AndroidRuntime(692):  at com.example.database.DBUse$2.onClick(DBUse.java:123)` what's DBUse.java:123 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in MainActivity

```
public Cursor getBusinessInfo(String name) {
     return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT business,address,phone,hours,website,type FROM Business  
    where name like ?", new String[]{"%"+name+"%"});
```

and in onClick

```
 //Informs the user what is being searched
private OnClickListener startName=new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick (View v) {

        Cursor cur=data.getBusinessInfo(dEdit.getText().toString()); 
        String result="";

        int iRow=cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        .....................
```

Instead of `SQLiteDatabase data;` change to `MainActivity data;` 
And change onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = new MainActivity(this);

    Button buttonName =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonName);
    buttonName.setOnClickListener(startName);



    Button buttonType =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonType);
    buttonType.setOnClickListener(startType);

    dEdit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    data.open();


    Cursor c = data.getAllTitles();
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{DisplayTitle(c);
    }while (c.moveToNext());
}   

    Cursor b = data.getAllTitles();

    if (b.moveToFirst())
        DisplayTitle(b);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this,"No business found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





}
```

Comment: change all your datab to data

Comment: Change your SQLiteDatabase; data to MainActivity data;

Comment: if I do that then I have to create a method for the rawQuery method in the main activity section so is that what I should do or is there another way around this?

Comment: Yes otherwise you cannot query at all move the query code to MainActivity and just return the cursor

Comment: okay so once I move that code to the MainActivity and create the Cursor rawQuery method I just copy over all of the code that I have for public void onClick (View v)?

Comment: in onClick all the codes except data.rawQuery and substitute that by data.getBusinessInfo as above

Comment: I'm confused as to what this method should look like. I currently have a lot of errors about not having a getBusinessInfo method. Am I creating that also?

Comment: create a method call getBusinessInfo in MainActivity as I posted above. and in onClick you call the getBusinessInfo as I posted above. Look at my answer again

Comment: would I need to create another method for the business type or can I use the same getBusinessInfo Cursor?

Comment: I do not understand elaborate your question.

Comment: in DBUse. I have two on click listeners that are searching the database by two different criteria. One is searching by the business name. The other is searching by the business type. Would I have to create another method for the button that is dealing with type since the one we created earlier is by name?

Comment: Yes you need to create another method call it getBusinessInfoByType(String type)

Comment: alright I did that now I am having trouble with one more line of my code I have edited my main activity class to show where the error is happening.

Comment: I edited your question changing in MainActivity and DbUse take a look. By the way you should change the name MainActivity to DbAdapter

Comment: After running my app on an emulator the app closed without any error in the logcat is there anything that I can do to fix this?

Comment: Without logcat nobody would not what the error is. Don't you have  a phone you can run on. Try rerun again.

Comment: My original problem has been solved in one of the names I was calling it by "Name" when I used "business" to denote the business name. Now my issue is that nothing is being displayed upon a successful search.

Comment: Why do you use the same Edit text for both?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you elaborate?

Comment: In both method you use dEdit.getText().toString() so there is only one editText and if the EditText has name of business then your call for type would be empty.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I only used one edit text because I thought that would be the best idea since I was trying to get information from it. I'm not really sure how to fix this though

Comment: Did you have business type in the edit text when you click on the type button? create another edit text with label type

Comment: I was under the impression that if I had the edittext button that whatever was in the box would be what was searched for. The button clicked would determine where the search would occur. Is this wrong?

Comment: How is the variable String result being used because it's never called again after the cursor adds data to the result.

Comment: Yes whatever in the edit box would be search. what String result are you taking about? in what method?

Comment: The one in the onClick() method in the DBUse class.

Comment: It is up to you to do whatever with it. This is your code, it is there in the beginning. For now it does not do anything? you can check if it is empty for the case of type business.

Comment: Yea but I'm asking how do I return the "results" variable since it gets all the data but then is not called again once it has everything and if I try and return it in the onClick method I get an error saying that results cannot be put into a variable.

Comment: You cannot just make result a class member and then you can access it

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: If you want to use result then make it private String result; and put it before onCreate like MainActivity data

Comment: could you edit the code like before so that I can see what you're talking about? If I add private String result; to where you're saying I still cannot type return result; in my onClick method.

Comment: No you cannot return what do you want to do with it? make a toast or what?

Comment: I want to make it a toast so that the records are displaying once a search has been done

Comment: When I make the toast nothing appears. I feel as if my database isn't populating from my DBActivity class. I'm going to try and figure that out on my own. THank you for all the help thus far.

Answer (score 0):

In DBUse, try calling Cursor.close() explicitly whenever you open one. You're opening several cursors, and no guarantee garbage collection is cleaning them up in a timely manner.

This may not do it, but it might, and will eliminate one possibility.